# Can I programatically update a Google Analytics filter?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

We have a constantly changing list of IPs that needs to be filtered out of google analytics, is there some API, or way to fetch the list of IPs to be included in a Google Analytics filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no , although this would be a great feature though. The best thing you can do is block ranges of IP, you can do this with the following format:-

```
192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255
```

Regex's to

```
^192\.168\.0\.([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
```

Google have an IP [range generation tool](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55572) to help you out with this.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my solution will be to manually script my way through the Analytics website using some linux command line tools then. Ranges won't do it for me. Maybe I'll do it with a JMeter script.

Comment: @DavidParks that would do it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this as part of their [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters).

Example in Python

```
# Note: This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object.
# See the Filters Developer Guide for details.

# This request creates a new filter.
try:
  analytics.management().filter().insert(
      accountId='123456',
      body={
          'name': 'My Domain Filter',
          'type': 'EXCLUDE',
          'excludeDetails': {
              'field': 'GEO_DOMAIN',
              'matchType': 'EQUAL',
              'expressionValue': 'example.com',
              'caseSensitive': False
              }
      }
  ).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```